# c2dm : how to receive the message in the device? (using PHP)

Tags: php, android, android-c2dm

I have the registration id and auth token for c2dm. And then I pass store these values in db. and using php, i could send one message to c2dm server. But my problem is I dont know how to receive the message in the application. I am not sure whether my way of getting the message is correct or not. Anyway i will give it below.

I have one activity which registers to the c2dm using registration intent. and one receiver to receive the reg_id and notification message. it is registering with c2dm and not to receive message.

### manifest

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"></action>
        <category android:name="my.android.c2dm"></category> 
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"></action>
        <category android:name="my.android.c2dm"></category>
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

### C2dmRegistration.class (activity)

```
    Intent objRegIntnet=new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
    objRegIntnet.putExtra("app",PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,new Intent(),0));
    objRegIntnet.putExtra("sender","mymail@gmail.com");
    startService(objRegIntnet);
```

### c2dmReceiver

```
public class c2dmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    private static String KEY = "c2dmPref";
    private static String REGISTRATION_KEY = "registrationKey";


    private Context context;



    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        this.context = context;
        if (intent.getAction().equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")) 
        {
                  handleRegistration(context, intent);
             } 
        else if (intent.getAction().equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"))
        {
            handleMessage(context, intent);
             }              
    }

     private void handleRegistration(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
       //handles registeration
     }
     private void handleMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
{

    String title= intent.getStringExtra("title");
    String message= intent.getStringExtra("msg");
    Toast.makeText(context,"title : "+title+"\n message : "+message,1).show();
    //Do whatever you want with the message
}
```

please tell what is the mistake i have done...

### UPDATE

Hi all, the same code is woring for me today. The mistake i have done is with php code. instaed of passing the values as POST, i sent it was as GET. When I changed it to POST, the toast message is showing. but yet some problems are there.

The title, and msg values are null here.
my php code is :

```
function sendMessageToPhone($authCode, $deviceRegistrationId, $msgType, $messageText)
 {
       //$messageText="have a nice day";
       //$msgtype="important";
       $headers = array('Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=' . $authCode);
       $data = array(
        'registration_id' => $deviceRegistrationId,
        'collapse_key' => $msgType,
        'data.message' => $messageText
                        );
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send");
      if ($headers)
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
      $response = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $response;
    }
```

Actually i am not sure what type of values should use for collapse_key, and data.message variables.

Please help me...
Thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the way of giving collapse_key and and data..
collapse_key should be a string which is a name for a group of messages or a a parthicular type of messages. If we send more than one message with same collapse_key, the latest message will be sent to the device from c2dm server.

Example : $collapse_key = "important";

And the data. is the important thing. This will contain the message that we want to send.

Ex: if we want to send a message "Have a nice day", then i should give a key name to it. 
    data.="Have a nice day";
here 'wishes' is the key. And in receiver, i should retreive the message with the same key name.

```
private void handleMessage(Context context, Intent intent) 
{  
      String mywish= intent.getStringExtra("wishes");    
      Toast.makeText(context,"my wishes : "+mywish,1).show(); 
}
```

Sorry to all..

Answer (score 2):

This is my code I have use it for receiving notification form C2DM server, it also shows the notification on notification bar. It is running find you can compare your code with my code and correct the error if any .
I hope this is help.

/**
 * Base class for C2D message receiver. Includes constants for the strings used
 * in the protocol.
 */

```
public abstract class C2DMBaseReceiver extends IntentService {
private static final String C2DM_RETRY = "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RETRY";

public static final String REGISTRATION_CALLBACK_INTENT = "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION";
private static final String C2DM_INTENT = "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE";

// Logging tag
private static final String TAG = "C2DM";

// Extras in the registration callback intents.
public static final String EXTRA_UNREGISTERED = "unregistered";

public static final String EXTRA_ERROR = "error";

public static final String EXTRA_REGISTRATION_ID = "registration_id";

public static final String ERR_SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE = "SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE";
public static final String ERR_ACCOUNT_MISSING = "ACCOUNT_MISSING";
public static final String ERR_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED = "AUTHENTICATION_FAILED";
public static final String ERR_TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS = "TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS";
public static final String ERR_INVALID_PARAMETERS = "INVALID_PARAMETERS";
public static final String ERR_INVALID_SENDER = "INVALID_SENDER";
public static final String ERR_PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR = "PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR";

// wakelock
private static final String WAKELOCK_KEY = "C2DM_LIB";

private static PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;
private final String senderId;

/**
 * The C2DMReceiver class must create a no-arg constructor and pass the
 * sender id to be used for registration.
 */
public C2DMBaseReceiver(String senderId) {
    // senderId is used as base name for threads, etc.
    super(senderId);
    this.senderId = senderId;
}

/**
 * Called when a cloud message has been received.
 */
protected abstract void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent);

/**
 * Called on registration error. Override to provide better error messages.
 * 
 * This is called in the context of a Service - no dialog or UI.
 */
public abstract void onError(Context context, String errorId);

/**
 * Called when a registration token has been received.
 */
public void onRegistrered(Context context, String registrationId)
        throws IOException {

}

/**
 * Called when the device has been unregistered.
 */
public void onUnregistered(Context context) {
}

@Override
public final void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    try {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        if (intent.getAction().equals(REGISTRATION_CALLBACK_INTENT)) {
            handleRegistration(context, intent);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(C2DM_INTENT)) {
            //**C2DM Start

               Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();


                String pushNo =extras != null ? extras.getString("pushNo"):"";
                String scoreId =extras != null ? extras.getString("scoreId"):"";
                String notfId =extras != null ? extras.getString("notfId"):"";
                String fromId =extras != null ? extras.getString("fromId"):"";
                String toId =extras != null ? extras.getString("toId"):"";
                String matchId =extras != null ? extras.getString("matchId"):"";
                String msg =extras != null ? extras.getString("msg"):"";


                String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
                NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
                int icon = R.drawable.icon;    
                CharSequence tickerText = "Notification Receive";
                long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

                Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

                Context context1 = context;
                //*****************
                final int CUSTOM_VIEW_ID = 1;
                RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification_layout);
                contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.icon);
                contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "Racquetime \n"+msg);

                notification.contentView = contentView;


              notification.defaults=Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE+Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
              Intent notificationIntent;
              if(GUIStatics.boolLoginStatus)
              {
                  notificationIntent = new Intent(this,ShowAllNotificationActiviry.class);
              }
              else{
                   notificationIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
              }
              notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
                notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

                notificationIntent.putExtra("Tag", "C2DMBaseReceiver");
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
                notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;
                mNotificationManager.notify(CUSTOM_VIEW_ID, notification);

                //**C2DM End
        //  onMessage(context, intent);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(C2DM_RETRY)) {
            C2DMessaging.register(context, senderId);
        }
    } finally {
        // Release the power lock, so phone can get back to sleep.
        // The lock is reference counted by default, so multiple
        // messages are ok.

        // If the onMessage() needs to spawn a thread or do something else,
        // it should use it's own lock.
        mWakeLock.release();
    }
}

/**
 * Called from the broadcast receiver. Will process the received intent,
 * call handleMessage(), registered(), etc. in background threads, with a
 * wake lock, while keeping the service alive.
 */
static void runIntentInService(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (mWakeLock == null) {
        // This is called from BroadcastReceiver, there is no init.
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                WAKELOCK_KEY);
    }
    mWakeLock.acquire();

    // Use a naming convention, similar with how permissions and intents are
    // used. Alternatives are introspection or an ugly use of statics.
    String receiver ="com.commonsware.android.c2dm.C2DMReceiver";
    intent.setClassName(context, receiver);

    context.startService(intent);

}

private void handleRegistration(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String registrationId = intent
            .getStringExtra(EXTRA_REGISTRATION_ID);
    String error = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_ERROR);
    String removed = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_UNREGISTERED);

    if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "dmControl: registrationId = " + registrationId
                + ", error = " + error + ", removed = " + removed);
    }

    if (removed != null) {
        // Remember we are unregistered
        C2DMessaging.clearRegistrationId(context);
        onUnregistered(context);
        return;
    } else if (error != null) {
        // we are not registered, can try again
        C2DMessaging.clearRegistrationId(context);
        // Registration failed
        Log.e(TAG, "Registration error " + error);
        onError(context, error);
        if ("SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE".equals(error)) {
            long backoffTimeMs = C2DMessaging.getBackoff(context);

            Log.d(TAG, "Scheduling registration retry, backoff = "
                    + backoffTimeMs);
            Intent retryIntent = new Intent(C2DM_RETRY);
            PendingIntent retryPIntent = PendingIntent
                    .getBroadcast(context, 0 /* requestCode */, retryIntent,
                            0 /* flags */);

            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, backoffTimeMs,
                    retryPIntent);

            // Next retry should wait longer.
            backoffTimeMs *= 2;
            C2DMessaging.setBackoff(context, backoffTimeMs);
        }
    } else {
        try {
            onRegistrered(context, registrationId);
            C2DMessaging.setRegistrationId(context, registrationId);
            GUIStatics.registrationID=registrationId;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Registration error " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My messages only made it through when i started using:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

String message = (String)extras.get("message");

Log.d("Tag", "msg:" + message);
```